# Alternative to the explanation of large scales phenomena

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, dark-matter, dark-energy, modified-gravity

I've been reading a lot trough different articles about dark-matter and dark-energy and how they could explain observations such as the acceleration of the expansion of the universe or the gravitational pull of galaxies.

But what I ask myself is why? Why were these objects introduced in the first place? Why did physicists jump to conclusion saying this was another kind of unknown matter (which seems to me as a giant leap), and what are the reasons that made them follow this lead? Couldn't we consider that matter "simply" has exotic properties at large scales, just like it has at microscopic scales, which seems more fitting to me.

Are their any leads or theories that try to explain these phenomena without introducing  the concept of dark-matter/energy?

Comment: Well you have a couple of options. People tend to use occam’s razor to check which theory would be the best.

Comment: Here’s another view. We know that the matter has to have positive mass to exert G forces. It also should not interact with light hence its invisible. Hence scientists call it dark matter.

Comment: Occam's razor doesn't seem to be relevant here though: introducing a new type of matter is extremely complex and unintuitive

Comment: why introduce extremely complex stuff like exotic matter, when we can introduce dark matter.

Comment: But dark matter IS complex, so complex that we don't even know what it is!

Comment: exotic matter is even more complex because its exotic. It behaves differently than ordinary matter. We have no real good theory for it. Maybe dark matter could be exotic matter. We may not know. But scientists just named it dark because we cannot see it but we can only observe its effects.

Comment: When I was talking about exotic matter what I meant was dark matter

Comment: dark matter may or may not be exotic. We need to find out and it’s one of the biggest mysteries in current modern physics